# How put Minimize in place of min in a typical optimization problem?

Tags: math-mode

The typical is

```
$\displaystyle{\min_{x\in S} f(x)}$
```

but I want to view the word "Minimize" in place of "mín"

how can I obtain this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using `amsmath` you can set this up as a starred version of a math operator so that the limits get correctly placed.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareMathOperator*{\minimize}{minimize}

\begin{document}
$\displaystyle{\minimize_{x\in S} f(x)}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: I was about to enter the same answer.

Answer (score 10):

This solution requires no preamble definitions:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$\underset{x \in S}{\text{minimize}} f(x)$
\end{document}
```

[image]